# Behavior of the giant component of an Erdos-Renyi graph near p = 1/n

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

what is the behavior of an Erdos-Renyi random graph with p = (1 + f(n))/n with $f(n)=o(1)$? If $f(n)=0$ then it has size about $n^{2/3}$, but what if the probability is perturbed slightly, say with $f(n)=1/\log n$ or something a bit larger? (I'm interested in the answer on both sides, $\pm$.)

Comment: Have you looked at Alon & Spencer's "The Probabilistic Method"?  I don't have the text with me at the moment, but they have a chapter on the evolution of $G(n,p)$.